# Advantage Database Server - sp_Reindex on a free table

Tags: advantage-database-server, reindex

How can I re-index a free table that is not associated with a data dictionary?
  I've tried specifying just the table's name, table's name with extension, and full path to table:

```
execute procedure sp_Reindex('Accounts', 1024);
execute procedure sp_Reindex('Accounts.adt', 1024);
execute procedure sp_Reindex('D:\DataFiles\Accounts.adt', 1024);
```

All of those get the same error: The specified database object name is not valid. "Accounts" is not a table or view in the data dictionary.

EDIT:  The correct way to go about this is to use a "free table" connection, not a connection to a data dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a connection with ARC to the folder containing your free tables and run the same store procedure or open them with an ads table component and call
the adsreindex method of this component.